# PHP POST WITH DATATABLE PAGINATION

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Sorry if I am repeating the question, I have a HTML FORM page which displays the employee_id & attendance check box (IN, OUT) using datatable.

I made pagination with initial load value in the screen as 10, the data are loaded from mysql DB and all the data loads perfectly with pagination. I will update attendance status of each employee which checkbox and submit the form.

Once i submit the form, i called the PHP _POST `(if(isset($_POST['save'])))` , inside this i am trying to get the value of all employee_id & checkbox value but, i can able to get only first 10 rows, remaining in page 2,3,4,5 are not available, is there any option to get them, i tried with `jquery` for each too but it also alerts on first 10 rows.

Please help me out.

I need to post the data to database from data table regardless of pagination either using PHP post method (or) Jquery.

Comment: Please, post your code..

Answer (score 0):

If you using pagination by `LIMIT` in database query there is, of course, no way you would get more than 10 rows, so, your `<form>` submit will not give you more than those 10 data arrays you can save to database.

Can you explain why you need to update **all** rows in database? Because limiting by pagination guarantees that other rows will not be affected (if query is right).